# Java - Equation issues

Tags: java

I have an equation in my application that works this way:
user enter a number `X` (double) to use it in this equation:

```
double m = X * 0.015;
double resultIWant = X - m;
```

Note that if `m` has more than 3 digits after comma I take exactly 3 digits without rounding by using this function:

```
public static double threeDigitsAfterCommaWithoutRounding(double retenue) {
    return Math.floor(retenue * 1000) / 1000;
}
```

but I'm getting wrong calculation result :
**Example:**
if `X = 1359.532`
this is what I get in console:

```
1359.532 * 0.015 = 20.392979999999998
m = 20.392 (After using the function above)
1359.532 - 20.392 = 1339.1399999999999 !!!!
```

So the result should be `1339.14` and not `1339.1399999999999`
What am I missing ?

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating point arithmetics, where precision is made up and the digits don't matter. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @Dragondraikk Thnx for your help